# Boundary value problems for fourth order ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to solve a set of equations which are fourth order equations. I want to get the value of w

[image]

```
1/r ((-0.2409850746268657` + 
    270.59999999999997` r^2 ω^2) ψ[r] +
 r (0.08050746268656715` Derivative[1][ψ][r] + 
    r (0.013388059701492531` (ψ^′′)[r] + 
       r (-0.01791044776119403` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r] - 0.002238805970149254` r 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "4", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r])))) == 0
ψ[0.4`] == 0
Derivative[1][ψ][0.4`] == 0
-0.34` n^2 ψ[1] + 
0.34` Derivative[1][ψ][1] + (ψ^′′)[1] == 0
9 (2.66 ψ[1] - 1.66 Derivative[1][ψ][1]) - 
1. Derivative[1][ψ][1] + 1. (ψ^′′)[1] + 1. 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1] == 0
```

It's too hard to me to solve; I hope someone can help me.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NDSolve` does not recognize `(ψ^′′)[r]`, by which I assume you mean `ψ''[r]`.  Additionally, the quantities `n` and `ω` are undefined, so I set them both to `1`.  With these changes,

```
eq = {((-0.2409850746268657 + 276.03905999999995*r^2)*ψ[r] + 
    r*(0.08050746268656715*Derivative[1][ψ][r] + 
    r*(0.013388059701492531*Derivative[2][ψ][r] + 
    r*(-0.01791044776119403*Derivative[3][ψ][r] - 
    0.002238805970149254*r*Derivative[4][ψ][r]))))/r == 0, 
    ψ[0.4] == 0, Derivative[1][ψ][0.4] == 0, 
    -0.34*ψ[1] + 0.34*Derivative[1][ψ][1] + Derivative[2][ψ][1] == 0, 
    9*(2.66*ψ[1] - 1.66*Derivative[1][ψ][1]) - 1.*Derivative[1][ψ][1] + 
    1.*Derivative[2][ψ][1] + 1.*Derivative[3][ψ][1] == 0};
s = NDSolveValue[eq, ψ, {r, .4, 1}];
LogPlot[-s[r], {r, .4, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, ψ}, 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]

Other values for `n` and `ω` will, of course, produce different results.  I hope this meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices.I just copy the code and run it but failed,"NDSolveValue::bvluc:“ and it can't yield the plot

Comment: At the same time,I try to slove the problem with  bvp4c of Matlab.

Comment: @1112131424  I just copied the code from my answer above, and it ran as before.  I am using Mathematica 10.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 9.0

Comment: I just copied the code and run it with Mathematica 10.1,getting the same answer as you,I have been stuck in this problem for a long time,thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To do so, it is very helpful to take the two-minute introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion，you are great.

Comment: I have no jurisdiction now,"Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly-displayed post score"

Comment: I did it just now.thank you!